# Making a graph with ggplot2 out of an excel file with multiple groups

Tags: ggplot2, linegraph

I want to make a line plot with ggplot2 from an excel file of 5 different groups, related to the beta methylation values compared to the probes.

[image: excel file first rows]

[image: i would like to have it like this but then with a lot more data]

i tried different scripts from other websites but i dont understand how i could use my excel file and then make it in to a line plot like the figure with multiple values.

Comment: Hi @liselot. Approaching this in two parts will help you work out a solution, and will improve any programming questions you need help with. First tackle the data import and wrangling, that is getting your Excel data into some sort of object in R. Once you have that data frame, you'll have something to share on Stackoverflow (*i.e.* `dput(dataframe)`) if you have a question regarding `ggplot` code. I'd look at [readxl](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/) as a starting point for getting your data into R. If you run into issues, please edit this question with the code you've tried and the issue/error